# combine all forEach of an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have an object of objects as below

```
data = {
  Sam: { details: [ /* array items */ ] },
  Jill: { details: [ /* array items */ ] },
  Bill: { details: [ /* array items */ ] },
}
```

Then I have the code below to filter the data based on the name

```
filteredData = {};

Object.keys(data).forEach((name) => {
  filteredData[name] = data[name];
});
```

I call this in a constructor as below to get the `details` of the particular name

```
vis.dataFilteredTemp = filteredData[vis.name];
vis.dataFiltered = vis.dataFilteredTemp["details"];
```

if `vis.name` is `Jill`, then the output is `{details: Array(3)}` & this works just fine.

Now, I want the details of all names with is `filteredData` method. How can I do it?
The out put expected is `{details: Array(13)}}` if I do `vis.dataFilteredTemp = filteredData[]` (empty array is passed). 13 arrays because arrays of all names are added up.

Since I am working with d3.csv, I am unable to pass the `data` directly to the constructor. Can any one help?

Comment: Make `filteredData` as an array and push everything into it?

Comment: btw ... the second code block which aggregates `filteredData` via `keys` and `forEach` is obsolete (or it doesn't make any sense) for it just creates a shallow copy of `data`.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Yes. `filteredData` just creates the shallow copy but since I am using d3, I cannot directly use the data in a class object. I have to have this aggregation & then call is as needs in the class (based on the graph I want to plot)

Comment: @moys ... maybe, but then not like that ... how about `copiedData = Object.assign({}, data)` or `copiedData = { ...data }`? Even `copiedData = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data))` was a better choice than what the OP came up with.

Comment: @PeterSeliger OK. Will try. New to JS, so not sure about the possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over the [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), and use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to merge each array's `details`.

```js
const data = {
  Sam: { details: [1,2,3,4]},
  Jill: { details: [4,5,6] },
  Bill: { details: [7,8,9,10,11,12] }
};

function getData(data, name = '') {
  if (name) return { details: data[name].details };
  return { details: Object.values(data).flatMap(arr => arr.details) };
}

console.log(getData(data));
console.log(getData(data, 'Jill'));
```

Comment: the method should be able to output both shallow copy (just like `filteredData` is doing) and the complete data based on how I call it. Currently if is do `filteredData['Jill']`, i get data related to Jill, I want to be able to get this as all as if i pass and empty array `filteredData[]`, I should be able to get that whole data (basically the data we began with). Hope I am making sense.

Comment: Yes. This works perfectly. Thank you very much. U-Voted & accepted as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you should use Array.reduce

```
const data = {
  Sam: { details: [1,2] },
  jenn: { details: [3,4] },
  kurt: { details: [6, 9 , 10, 16] }
};

const result = Object.values(data).reduce((acc = {details: []}, val) => {
  acc.details.push(...val.details);
  return acc;
});

console.log(result.details);
```

outputs : `[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 16]`

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3g8ankfh/3/)